# Reading formula from a different collection

Tags: mongodb

Here is my scenario:

- I have 2 XLS files :

  - One with 5 columns : date, service, value1, value2, Value3
  - One with the formulas to apply: Service, Type_of_aggregation, columns_to_aggregate
    According to the service you apply a formula (sum or avg of the values of a column.)

Questions: 
- How can i tell mongodb to retrieve and apply the specified formula ?

Example:

- We insert both XLS files into seperate collections.
- We somehow trigger off the calculation: example: For Service1 do a Sum of all the values of colunm_value1.
- We store the result in a new collection

I hope you understand what i am trying to do and hoping to get some help on the best way to do this.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't quite know what XLS has to do with this in the first place, but can you give an example of how those documents actually look like - in the form of JSON documents that you'd import into MongoDB?

Comment: You can't "tell" MongoDb to do that. You'll need to write some middleware to load your files and run the aggregations using your favorite programming language.